# Assigning Insets from an Array - Java

Tags: java, arrays, jtextarea, insets

I have the following code which uses one of the `JTextAreas` from an array of such Objects to assign the `Insets` of a `JTextArea` for my program. The code is as follows:

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*; 

public class MainComponents
{ 
     private final static JTextField[] Input = new JTextField[10];

     public MainComponents(final Container P, final JFrame frame)
     { 

         P.setLayout(null);
         final Insets insets = P.getInsets();
         final Dimension InputInsets = Input[0].getPreferredSize();  //?

         ...
      }
}
```

Where I have the `//?` is where I get an Exception that tells me `java.lang.NullPointerException` occurs at this line. I cannot find the reason that `Input[0]` would be null if I assigned them alll to be `JTextAreas`. Am I declaring something incorrectly in the array?

Thank you.

Comment: Where did you assign them all to be JTextAreas?

Comment: I thought I did, but clearly I did not.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have initialized an array of JTextField. But each element in the array is still not initialized.

```
private final static JTextField[] Input = new JTextField[10];

Input[0] = new JTextField(); //And then perform operation on 0th element
```

To throw more light on this,

Whenever you initialize any primitive array in java, it will allocate memory continuously based on the passed data type.

For example,

```
int[] intArray = new int[10]; // Assuming int is 4 bytes, 40 bytes allocated continuously
double[] doubleArray = new double[10]; // Assuming double is 8 bytes, 80 bytes allocated continuously.
```

And note that intArray or doubleArray is a reference that is going to point to the starting memory location of the allocated value. This is the reason arrays are faster while searching by index. when you do a intArray[5], all it does is go to initial address of intArray + (5 * sizeof(integer)) will give the value directly.

However, things are a bit differnt in case of Objects. When I do

```
Object[] objArray = new Object[10];
```

This will create again a continuous 10 references in memory. Assuming a reference is 2 bytes, it will need 20 bytes continously. And all these are just references that are pointing to no where, ie they are null. It is our duty to invoke them explicitly.

Comment: Ah. I did not realize I had to declare each one to be a JTextField. I thought it was implicit.

Comment: Nope.. It is implicit only in primitives. For example. new int[10] would have initialized 10 integers. Whereas in all other objects, we have to initialize them by ourselves.

Answer (score 0):

all you did with this line:

```
 private final static JTextField[] Input = new JTextField[10];
```

is initialize the array. You didn't initialize any of the array members (they're all still null). You need to iterate over the array and place an object in each slot before you can use it.

Answer (score 0):

This line `JTextField[] Input = new JTextField[10]` allocates array. But each element of this array is null. So, attempt to turn to the element and call its methods throws

```
NullPointerExcetption. You have to initialize the array, e.g. 
for (int i = 0;  i < input.length;  i++) {
    input[i] = new JTextArea();
}
```

now you can access `input[0]`;